# Post images from the DataBase

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a DataBase called iiti which has a String called ImgName, 
the Value of ImgName, which is the name of an Image in the Drawable folder.
I want to post that image on an imageView

```
TextView descText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        descText.setText(iiti.getneighborhood() + "\n");

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(iiti.getLatLat(),"drawable",this.getPackageName());
    iv.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

the code above well only just make the ImageView a white blank image and if i try to use this code

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.hii);
        //hii is a png image in the drawable folder
```

this is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="London"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/neighborhoodText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cityText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="West End"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cityText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/london_photo"/>

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the app just crashes this is the Logcat:

```
03-27 15:21:10.984 9542-9542/com.example.android.mymaps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.mymaps, PID: 9542
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(110250000bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Post the error stacktrace and xml file

Comment: i edited it and added the Logcat and the XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your Activity:

```
val resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(iiti.getImgName(), "drawable", this.getPackageName())
iv.setImageResource(resourceId)
```

Or this in your Fragment:

```
int resourceId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(iiti.getImgName(), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
iv.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

In case of any problems check [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

EDIT:

This is your crash:

```
Canvas: trying to draw too large(110250000bytes) bitmap.
```

So bitmap you are trying to draw is to large... that's it. Compress your file, change it's size or do whatever shrinks it's size. And if you are hasitating - this file is 110.25MB large.

Comment: can you please have another look at the question above

Comment: What question? You didn't edit anything. I've edited my answer to show what I meant by 'context'

Comment: i don't get it what can I do all the Images are under 150kb so i don't think that they are stressing a prolem

Comment: Crash = your bitmap is to big. What to do? Make it smaller. Search in google for tools for optimizing image size

Comment: thanks for the help the hii image is the one causing the bitmap error and i fixed the bit map error

Answer (score 1):

scale down the image as:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       resourceId);
iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight/2, false));
```